# How long do cookies live in a mobile ecosystem?

Tags: cookies, mobile-website

I'm aware of different ways to specify cookie lifetime in desktop, but what about mobile? I suppose some cookies may "die" earlier than configured because of lack of the space on mobile device. Does anyone have any research on this?

Answer (score 0):

It is more of a network issue than space on the phone. Some mobile networks may discard cookie information. This was the case with many networks as recent as 3 years ago. Unfortunately I don't have any information about which ones.